# Rails Routing Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am creating an API similar to that of Flickr's and I am having some problems with on of the routes. I need something the following to all be routed to the same controller/action:

- /services/api/photos.comments.getList.html
- /services/api/photos.getList.html
- /services/api/photos.search.html
- /services/api/users.photos.comments.getList.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're trying to pass photos, comments etc as variables then

```
match 'services/api/:photos/:comments' => 'controller#method'
```

but I'm not sure what you're quite trying to do. It would seem to make more sense, assuming you are passing these as values, to put the getList and search as separate methods

```
match 'services/api/getList/:photos/:comments' => 'controller#getList'
match 'services/api/search/:photos/:comments' => 'controller#search'
```

Comment: It's just the documentation for my API. I have all of the methods stored in a table along w/ their description, arguments, etc. I just need to pass one argument (photos.comments.getList, or photos.getList) and a .html extension.

Comment: if that's all you need then just use a wildcard: match 'service/api/*html' => 'controller#method' not sure this is the Rails way though, you'd get much more flexibility using the controller methods to manage the response rather than storing everything in a table